# jQuery Auto-Selecting an option in drop-down

Tags: jquery

I am trying to auto-select an option in a drop down when a specific image is clicked, I have made a JsFiddle to show my current code, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/CWTx6/

HTML:

```
<img class="auto-image" data-name="01" style="cursor:pointer;" src="img/Plaque/Horses/01.png">

<select name="productOption[]" id="product-option-11" class="product-option product-option-select" data-force="0" data-title="Image">
    <option value="0" data-price="0">Please select...</option>
    <option value="11::167" data-price="0.0000" data-modify="0">01</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$('.auto-image').on('click', function() {
    var search = $(this).data('name');
    console.log('Click is being run, search has been varred as: ' + search);

    $('.product-option-select').find('option[text=' + search + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');

    var found = $('.product-option-select').find('option[text=' + search + ']').val();
    console.log('Oh, and I found the option, value is: ' + found);
});
```

At the moment the console displays this:

```
Click is being run, search has been varred as: 01
Oh, and I found the option, value is: undefined
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CWTx6/2/)**

```
$('.product-option-select').find('option:contains(' + search + ')')
```

---

1. `find('option[text=' + search + ']')` is a wrong selector in this case. Use **[:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)**
2. You did not include reference to jQuery in your fiddle.

---

Full JS code- modified :

```
$('.auto-image').on('click', function() {
    var search = $(this).data('name');
    console.log('Click is being run, search has been varred as: ' + search);

    $('.product-option-select').find('option:contains(' + search + ')').attr('selected', 'selected');

    var found = $('.product-option-select').find('option:contains(' + search + ')').val();

    console.log('Oh, and I found the option, value is: ' + found);
});
```

---

Alternative to `:contains()`,

```
$(".product-option-select option").filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == search;
}).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: This works, BUT - I have other options with the text "101", "102", etc, so it picks up 101 instead of 01 when clicked.

Comment: Don't worry, I just added .first() after the find, works perfectly.

Comment: Okay great. Goodluck.